# Turn vector equation into matrix multiplication

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, vector

I have physical equations of motion that describe the dependence of one vector field on the components of another vector field. Without getting too much into detail, my differential equations involve a double curl that mixes the vector components on one side of the equation. Furthermore, I would like to discretize the space on which these equations are defined. So far I was able to set up the discretized equations:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\ \begin{pmatrix}
\vdots\\
P_x(i)\\
P_y(i)\\
P_z(i)\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\vdots\\
A_y(i)-A_y(i+1)\\
-A_x(i)+A_x(i+1)-a*A_z(i)\\
b*A_y(i)\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
where a and b are some arbitrary constants and $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{P}$ are the two vector fields whose relation I want to determine. The lattice coordinates in one dimension are written as i (e.g. $\frac{d}{dt} P_x(7) = A_y(7)-A_y(8)$).

Is there any way to automatically turn this into a matrix multiplication? I would want the result to look something like

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\ \begin{pmatrix}
\vdots\\
P_x(i)\\
P_y(i)\\
P_z(i)\\
P_x(i+1)\\
P_y(i+1)\\
P_z(i+1)\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
\ddots & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & \ddots\\
\ddots & -1 & 0 & -a & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ddots\\
\ddots & 0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots\\
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots  & \ddots\\
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots  & \ddots\\
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots  & \ddots\\
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  & \ddots  & \ddots\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\vdots\\
A_x(i)\\
A_y(i)\\
A_z(i)\\
A_x(i+1)\\
A_y(i+1)\\
A_z(i+1)\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix} \tag{2}
$$

You can already see from this example that there is some regularity as P(i+1), P(i+2), etc. will have the same entries in the matrix as the ones for P(i), only that the entries within the matrix will be at different positions.

So the question is: If I gave you the vector on the right-hand side of equation (1), could you give me the matrix on the right-hand side of equation (2)?

Comment: `SparseArray[{
   {i_, j_} /; Mod[i, 3] == 1 && j == i + 1 :> 1,
   {i_, j_} /; Mod[i, 3] == 1 && j == i + 4 :> -1,
   {i_, j_} /; Mod[i, 3] == 2 && j == i + 1 :> 1,
   {i_, j_} /; Mod[i, 3] == 2 && j == i + 3 :> -a,
   {i_, j_} /; Mod[i, 3] == 2 && j == i + 4 :> -1,
   {i_, j_} /; Mod[i, 3] == 0 && j == i + 1 :> b,
   ...},
  {n, n}]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2, I tried your suggestion and must be doing something wrong because when I copy-paste what you wrote, into v12.1 on a Mac, it gives an error "Syntax::sntxf" saying SparseArray cannot be followed by what is following it.  I cleared variables so I don't think that is my problem and unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @MarkR The ellipsis is an ellipsis, not a `RepeatedNull`.  The code is about as complete as the post and is merely a hint.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - thanks for letting me know.  I should have realized it was just showing the general idea.  I should have looked more closely before trying to copy-paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`CoefficientArrays`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays). For example:

```
m = CoefficientArrays[
    {
    Ay[i]-Ay[i+1],
    -Ax[i]+Ax[i+1]-a Az[i],
    b Ay[i]
    },
    {Ax[i],Ay[i],Az[i],Ax[i+1],Ay[i+1],Az[i+1]}
][[2]];
m //Normal //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
>  -1 & 0 & -a & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Very neat solution!